# Removing non standard ASCII characters from Firebird query result

Tags: excel, firebird, firebird2.5

We use ODBC connections to download data from Ostendo, which is based on Firebird 2.5, into Excel.

We have issues with connections of table fields whose data contain non standard ascii characters. These generally come from emails that have been copied and pasted into a field called "jobnotes" (which is data type blob).

Is it possible to go through each character to check if it's char number is greater than 126 and if so replace it with "{?}" or replace the whole field with "Not downloaded - contains special chars*." Or is there a function that already does this? Most of what I have found online is people with language issues, but for us it is a mix of language and characters used for engineering.

Comment: There is nothing built-in for this. You could use `SUBSTRING(...)` and `ASCII_VAL(...)` to check each character, but you will need to write such logic yourself. This is likely easier done in your client language (eg for Excel, in VBA)

Comment: what is `data type blob` ? there is no such thing in Firebird. There is either binary blob or text blob. Binary blobs do not have "characters". And text blobs might be of different charsets, so there can be up to 4 bytes per one character. What specific "issues" do you have? better course would be just to read all data as is into your software, and then make your software to discard or replace data it can not use, like extended characters. Can you connect to the databse with exactly the same charset as Ostendo is using? Also, have you other options than ODBC (seems not actively mantained) ?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I was having issues downloading the information into Excel to edit in the first place. I managed to download it into Excel (without crashing) and then find the offending data and change it accordingly (it was 3 periods becoming and ellipses in case you cared). In the end it didn't solve the original offending issue. But I did manage to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use syntax like" substring(src_str similar ) otherwise if you need somethink more simple, you can create your own function like:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION F_REMOVE_SPECIALCHARS(
  IN_STR VARCHAR(8000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
declare variable IN_SIZE integer;
declare variable IDX integer;
declare variable OUT_STR varchar(8000);
begin
  /* Function Text */
  in_size = char_length(IN_STR);
  idx = 1;
  out_str = '';
  while (idx < in_size+1) do
   begin
    if (lower(substring(in_str from idx for 1)) in
                  ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i',
                   'l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t',
                   'u','v','x','y','k','j','@','-','_',
                   '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
                   '0',' ')

    ) then
     begin
      out_str = out_str || substring(in_str from idx for 1);
     end
    idx = idx + 1;
   end
  return out_str;
end
```

in this case, you can maintain a selection of characters you need